# free inside thread causes Segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

Very confused over this. I've just started learning about pointers and have now decided to go a bit deeper and start experimenting with threads. What I'm trying to do is pass a pointer onto a thread, so (after `malloc`ing `data`) I call:

```
pthread_create(&ptThread, &ptAttr, newClient, (void *) data);
```

Inside the `newClient` function, I do what I need to do, and I decided (as there was a pointer allocated) to free it:

```
void *newClient(void *v) {
    // ...stuff happens here...

    free(v);
}
```

At the `free(v);` part, I get a Segmentation fault. So I used valgrind, and I got this saying it was an invalid free:

```
==1214== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==1214==    at 0x4023B6A: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==1214==    by 0x804F622: newClient (xxxxxx2.c:44)
==1214==    by 0x4032954: start_thread (pthread_create.c:300)
==1214==    by 0x4112E7D: clone (clone.S:130)
==1214==  Address 0x4 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

To add to the fire, as I quit my program, valgrind told me I had a memory leak because `v` wasn't `free`'d:

```
==1214== 8 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==1214==    at 0x4023F50: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==1214==    by 0x804F453: main (xxxxxx1.c:94)
```

My questions - how is it an invalid free? Is there something I'm missing here? Do I need to `free(v);`?

Comment: is `data` a simple pointer? please provide the relevant part of the code with variable definition and malloc.

Comment: Not enough code, but *data* doesn't look like a pointer you allocated with malloc().  If it was, you wouldn't have used the void* cast.  Don't free() stuff that wasn't allocated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `0x4` doesn't look like a valid address.

```
==1214==  Address 0x4 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

What I think is happening is that you are accidentally changing `v`. This may be because of a careless `memcpy` / `strcpy` overwriting the stack of `newClient`.

On another note, generally it is recommended that both `malloc` and `free` are done in the same thread. I heard some allocators are designed to do it more efficiently that way.

Comment: While many allocators are more efficient if `malloc`/`free` for a chunk occur in the same thread, many of the important uses of dynamic allocation with threads actually preclude that...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is already at the point where you `malloc` your `data`. It gets past around wrong (`0x4` isn't plausible) so probably you already have had problems there. A common error is to forget to include the header file and have `malloc` interpreted as returning `int` per default rules.

Casting almost always hides a programming or, worse, design error:

- don't cast the return value of `malloc`. `malloc` returns `void*`
  this is compatible with any other data type pointer
- don't cast pointers to `void*` as you do when calling `pthread_create`. All data type pointers are converted to `void*` without problems